# Why is GitHub causing me pain?

Tags: android, git, github, aide-ide

Ok I'm having this issue. I pushed (fresh repo) my Android app to my repo on Github from Android Studio. I then pulled it from AIDE on my tablet. I received no errors, even after pulling, from Android Studio. However, when I use AIDE I get errors such as invalid pack declaration (it's setup correctly). I change it to how it appears in the path, it works just fine (even tho in Android Studio my original setup was right). After that I get a bunch of errors saying R is  an unknown entity. R.Java is present, so that's not it. I added the suggested import and that branches off to more errors.

**Edit**

The commands I have been using are as follows:

On initial setup:

```
cd C:\...path here
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin <urltorepo>
git remote -v
git push origin master
```

updating:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "message"
git push origin master
```

and this is what I've been getting:

```
     warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in <file>
     The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

Comment: add up what command you have used and does the git gives any errors? r u using command line or eclipse to push or pull the code?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice I've edited to include what I've been doing. I use git shell, which is provided with the github app for windows

Comment: cool the command seems fine now what the issue?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice Was getting errors saying package name was incorrect even tho it wasn't, but I fixed it now by simply recreating the repo (kind of annoying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by recreating the repo and leaving the "Initialize this repository with a README" check blank